# How to read individual slide from ppt using tika package in python?

Tags: python-3.x, compare, apache-tika, python-pptx, tika-server

I want to compare data in two pptx file and show the differences if any using python.

I have tried with below code, but it is giving all content in single file. No way to segregate data based on slides.

I am able to read all content of pptx using tika but I need slide wise content to compare with other pptx file.

```
from tika import parser
parsed = parser.from_file('act.pptx')
act =parsed['content']
act=act.strip().replace('\n',' ')
```

Expected result is store each slide one text file.
Actual result is I am getting all slides data into one text file.

Comment: Input File format is pptx

Comment: Request the output as XHTML instead of plain text, then split on the page divs?

Comment: can you give sample code.

Comment: In Java it'd be http://tika.apache.org/1.21/examples.html#Fetching_just_certain_bits_of_the_XHTML , should be fairly similar through the python wrapper